# Create an Array in Swift from an NSData Object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdata

I'm trying to store an array of integers to disk in swift.  I can get them into an NSData object to store, but getting them back out into an array is difficult.  I can get a raw `COpaquePointer` to the data with `data.bytes` but can't find a way to initialize a new swift array with that pointer.  Does anyone know how to do it?

```
import Foundation

var arr : UInt32[] = [32,4,123,4,5,2];

let data = NSData(bytes: arr, length: arr.count * sizeof(UInt32))

println(data)  //data looks good in the inspector

// now get it back into an array?
```

Comment: archive / unarchive it, that is much easier and most common way to do such a thing.

Comment: archive/unarchive crashes here because it's not an array of objects, just int values.  I would have to change my array to Int objects.

Comment: sure, because you can archive objects only which conforms to `NSCoding` protocol. if you change the array from `Array<UInt32>` to `Array<NSNumber>`, you will be able to archive immediately.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the `getBytes` method of `NSData`:

```
// the number of elements:
let count = data.length / sizeof(UInt32)

// create array of appropriate length:
var array = [UInt32](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)

// copy bytes into array
data.getBytes(&array, length:count * sizeof(UInt32))

print(array)
// Output: [32, 4, 123, 4, 5, 2]
```

---

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8):** Swift 3 has a new type `struct Data`
which is a wrapper for `NS(Mutable)Data` with proper value semantics.
The accessor methods are slightly different.

*Array to Data:*

```
var arr: [UInt32] = [32, 4, UInt32.max]
let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &arr, count: arr.count))
print(data) // <20000000 04000000 ffffffff>
```

*Data to Array:*

```
let arr2 = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    Array(UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt32>(start: $0, count: data.count/MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride))
}
print(arr2) // [32, 4, 4294967295]
```

---

**Update for Swift 5:**

*Array to Data:*

```
let arr: [UInt32] = [32, 4, UInt32.max]
let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: arr, count: arr.count))
print(data) // <20000000 04000000 ffffffff>
```

*Data to Array:*

```
var arr2 = Array<UInt32>(repeating: 0, count: data.count/MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride)
_ = arr2.withUnsafeMutableBytes { data.copyBytes(to: $0) }
print(arr2) // [32, 4, 4294967295]
```

Comment: Swift changed the way to write array declarations, in Xcode Beta 5 you get an error saying: `Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type`. So in the 2nd line of your code the correct is: `var array = [UInt32](count: count, repeatedValue: 6)`

Comment: @Martin R: may i ask another similar question?
// CGFloat to NSData
var cgf: CGFloat = 5.123456
var f = Float(cgf)
var nsf = NSNumber(float: f)
var nsd = NSData(bytes: &nsf, length: sizeofValue(nsf))

The question is how can i convert nsdata back to CGFloat?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sifeng: `nsf` is a *pointer* to an object, so you cannot use that to pack the number into data. Just `var cgf: CGFloat = 5.123456 ; var data = NSData(bytes: &cgf, length: sizeofValue(cgf))` to pack and `var cgf1: CGFloat = 0 ; data.getBytes(&cgf1, length: sizeofValue(cgf1))` to unpack.

Comment: Wouldn't data length be divided by strideof(UInt32) since strideof measures the width of array elements e.g. type T in Array<T> ?

Comment: @Bobjt: It would not make a difference for "simple" types like Int, but generally you are right!

Comment: I think this answer is correct for `UInt32` but incorrect in the general case. The call to `UnsafeBufferPointer` should calculate the count by doing `data.count / MemoryLayout<Type>.stride`. If the stride is greater than the size, then using size will calculate an incorrect count.

Comment: @algal: `size` and `stride` are identical for all "simple" integer and floating point types (and for all types imported from C). But you are right, `stride` is the correct thing in the general case. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MartinR My pleasure. I believe you may have explained this matter to me originally, on an SO question not so long ago. :)

Comment: withUnsafeBufferPointer is now deprecated

Answer (score 15):

It's also possible to do this using an `UnsafeBufferPointer`, which is essentially an "array pointer", as it implements the `Sequence` protocol:

```
let data = NSData(/* ... */)

// Have to cast the pointer to the right size
let pointer = UnsafePointer<UInt32>(data.bytes)
let count = data.length / 4

// Get our buffer pointer and make an array out of it
let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt32>(start:pointer, count:count)
let array = [UInt32](buffer)
```

This eliminates the need for initializing an empty array with duplicated elements first, to then overwrite it, although I have no idea if it's any faster. As it uses the `Sequence` protocol this implies iteration rather than fast memory copy, though I don't know if it's optimized when passed a buffer pointer. Then again, I'm not sure how fast the "create an empty array with X identical elements" initializer is either.

Comment: This seems to currently work better, as the getBytes method was causing a crash.

Comment: seems getBytes is much faster, compared to this one. For 1349890 bytes using an "array pointer" took 0.034 sec, while getBytes only 0.005 sec

Comment: Getting following error : 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeRawPointer)'. because data.bytes is UnsafeRawPointer.  I am just trying to write equivalent code for const char* bytes = [data bytes];

Comment: Running into the same issue as Alix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic way to do it.

```
import Foundation

extension Data {
    func elements <T> () -> [T] {
        return withUnsafeBytes {
            Array(UnsafeBufferPointer<T>(start: $0, count: count/MemoryLayout<T>.size))
        }
    }
}

let array = [1, 2, 3]
let data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: array, count: array.count))
let array2: [Int] = data.elements()

array == array2
// IN THE PLAYGROUND, THIS SHOWS AS TRUE
```

You must specify the type in the `array2` line. Otherwise, the compiler cannot guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with Data to Array (I know for sure my array is going to be [String]), I am quite happy with this:

*NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: yourData)*

I hope it helps