# How to get back a float when added as bytes to a NSMutableData

Tags: swift, nsmutabledata

I am appending floats to a NSMutable to get a bytestream of a lot of floats.

```
for var i=0 ;i < 10000 ;i++{

   let myfloat=floatarray[i];
   testdata.appendBytes(&myfloat, length: sizeof(Float));
}
```

How do I get the array back from that stream ?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Mike.
I did as suggested.

```
// Have to cast the pointer to the right size
        let pointer = UnsafePointer<Float>(testdata.bytes)
        let count = testdata.length / sizeof(Float);

        // Get our buffer pointer and make an array out of it
        let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>(start:pointer, count:count)
        let array = [Float](buffer)


        print(String(array[0]));
```

Comment: You can use `subdataWithRange:`.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish be appending to an `NSMutableData`?

Comment: what the type is NSMutable ?

Comment: @user3441734 See the question title.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/24516400/1187415 works with a Float (or any other "scalar") array as well ...

Comment: Now if the Question code only compiled. It would also be nice it it used Swift syntax and variable CamelCase.

Comment: @zaph. I do this, because I realized, that this is the fastest way to write/read a lot of floats into/from a blobfield in SQLite.

Comment: @Maritn . Thank you very much. Got it to work. I updated the question with the solution.