# Attach an array of doubles to a mail in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to attach an array of doubles to a mail using the `MFMailComposeViewController` class. So far this is my code in the `ViewController` class:

```
func prepareMail(data:[Double]) {                
        // Compose the mail
        let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposer.setToRecipients(["mail@mail.com"])
        mailComposer.setSubject("subject")
        mailComposer.setMessageBody("Hello ", isHTML: false)

        // Name data files (accelerometer + label)
        let fileName = "file"

        if let dataToAttach = data {
            //Attach File
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(dataToAttach, mimeType: "text/plain", fileName: "\(fileName)")
            self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This code raises the following message:

> initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   [Double]

So here are my thoughts:

- **Option 1:** Convert the array of doubles to a string and send it as a plain/text file. My intuition, however, tells me that this is not a nice solution. I am not a fan of parsing.
- **Option 2:** Encode the array somehow and send it using another `mimetype` other than plain/text. I explored some options in [IANA mime Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/), but I am not familiar at all and do not know where to start with.

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Update your question with your attempts to solve your issue using your two options. Update your question with whatever issues you are having with those attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line `if let dataToAttach = data` because your data is `[Double]` and can't be `nil`, so you don't need to check of is `nil`, or you can change the parameters type to `[Double]?` to avoid this compiler error.

Replacing this:

```
if let dataToAttach = data {
            //Attach File
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(dataToAttach, mimeType: "text/plain", fileName: "\(fileNames[i])")
            self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

by this:

```
   func prepareMail(data:[Double]) {
    // Compose the mail
    let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposer.setToRecipients(["mail@mail.com"])
    mailComposer.setSubject("subject")
    mailComposer.setMessageBody("Hello ", isHTML: false)

    // Name data files (accelerometer + label)
    let fileName = "file"

    if let dataToAttach = data.map({String($0)}).joined(separator: "\n").data(using: .utf8)
    {
        mailComposer.addAttachmentData(dataToAttach, mimeType: "text/plain", fileName: "\(fileNames[i])")
        self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

will be enough.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am now testing adding this: let dataTx = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data, count: data.count)), which i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516170/create-an-array-in-swift-from-an-nsdata-object), since `Data` type is required as @rmaddy commented.